# I do not understand why my cell is not showing up?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I do not understand why my cell is not showing up even though I have the correct identifier and class

```
class homeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("p")
    let cell: homeTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "homeTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! homeTableViewCell
    
    return cell
}
```

}

The identifier is the same in both table view cell and here

Comment: are these functions are even get called ?

Comment: add breakpoint to test

Comment: Did you set the data source?

Comment: Yes I did set data source

Comment: `
class homeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    `

Comment: That is just saying that the 'homeViewController' class conforms to those protocols but do you also assign it to the delegate of the table view? (p.s. start your classes with a capital letter so HomeViewController)

Comment: In viewdidLoad method, you should write these code
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.datasource = self

If tableView outlet is available on your home view controller

Comment: I wrote that in viewdidload

Comment: Yes it is empty, I will use the debugger right now

Comment: Whenever I try printing something in these functions it does not show up in debugger

Comment: You should use different background colors to check where is the issue, In viewDid load assign tableView.backgroundcolor = .red, At cell for row at cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .blue. Then check which color is not available.

Comment: I cant use tableView unless I change class to UITableViewController

Comment: I found out the methods are not getting called

Comment: so you set delegate and dataSource in `viewDidLoad()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set delegate and dataSource for your tableview.

For ex:

```
this.tableView.delegate = self
this.tableView.dataSource = self
```

Answer (score 0):

drug an outlet of your tableview and set a name. suppose the name you set myTableView . **in viewDidLoad()**  write these 2 line of code.

```
myTableView.delegate = self
myTableView.dataSource = self
```

or in storyboard , press ctrl and drug your mouse with left clicking to the top header of storyboard view controller, then enable delegate and dataSource .

hope the problem will solve .
if you have any issue comment here.